# Direction of a force (action-reaction forces) problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

I had an AP Physics 2 questions that says during the collision, the molecule exerts a force with magnitude **F** on the wall, and then asks what properly describes the force acting on the wall. The answer was **-F**, and explains this through action-reaction pairs. I'm unsure as to why **F** is negative, can someone please explain this? I'm also willing to send the full question

Comment: F is already acting on the wall. I guess you mean "on the particle".

Answer (score 1):

Newton third law force pairs are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.
The negative sign indicate that one force has a direction of action in the opposite direction to the other.
The two forces might be $F\,\hat i$ and $F(-\hat i) = -F \,\hat i$